# Error in Vim when Installed Plugin

Tags: vim, bundle, vim-plugin

I installed VIM from repository in ubuntu 16.04. and installed plugin from 
[Link](https://github.com/hightman/vimrc)
for web Design and Web Development in PHP.

but i get this error : (head of Error)

```
    Error detected while processing /home/abolfazl/.vimrc:
line    7:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#rc
line    9:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
Error detected while processing /home/abolfazl/vimrc/vimrc.vundle:
line   11:
E492: 
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

and head of my ~/.vimrc config is :

```
"--------------------
" Use Vundle to manage bundles
"--------------------
set nocompatible        " be iMproved
filetype off            " required!
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle
call vundle#rc()

Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
source ~/.vim/vimrc.vundle

"--------------------
" General Settings
"--------------------
set bs=indent,eol,start
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the problem here is with your installation of vundle.

The instructions on the [repo page](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) instruct you to clone the repository with the following command:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

This will clone the repo into a path within your `~/.vim` folder. Your error message however, seems to be complaining about the file:

```
/home/abolfazl/vimrc/vimrc.vundle
```

This file is in a folder called `vimrc` - I'm fairly certain that this is the issue and that this folder should not exist.

So it appears as though it was installed to the wrong path.

Comment: I think the line `Bundle 'gmarik/vundle.vim'` needs to be changed to `Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'` and perhaps `source ~/.vim/vimrc.vundle` should also be removed from the .vimrc